# How to hide webbrowser navigations?

Tags: c#, winforms, navigation, browser

I have a form that on load show login form on webbrowser. When user login and then exit without loging out, it automatically logging him out on next start up and showing him again the login form. To logout from site 2 navigations needed but I don't user to see that navigations, I want the browser to be white until all navigations complete or something similar.

```
bool f = true;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wbLoad.Navigate("http://login.uid.me/?site=dmysite&ref=http://mysite.ucoz.com/");
}

private void wbLoad_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (f == true)
    {
        if (wbLoad.DocumentText.Contains("Sign up"))
        {
            wbLoad.Navigate("http://login.uid.me/?site=dmysite&ref=http://mysite.ucoz.com/");
            f = false;
        }
        else if (wbLoad.DocumentText.Contains("Log out"))
        {
            wbLoad.Navigate("http://mysite.ucoz.com/index/10");
            f = true;
        }
        else
        {
            wbLoad.Navigate("http://uid.me/logout/?mode=1&noajax=1");
            f = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `To logout from site 2 navigations....`- this statement is unclear. Can you make it more understandable?

Comment: I log out from site then I must logout from `uid.me` because logout is not logging you out completely, it just loggout you from site but then when you click login it loggin you in without asking username or password so thats why you need to logout from `uid.me` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging out means in most cases just removing cookies for current host. If it's your case, you can do it by using javascript. Note, that this JS will remove cookies only for current host. You can call it in `FormClosing` event

```
wbLoad.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the logout concept in Form Close event or some where else. So next time when user opens that time it will automatically redirects to login page. And need to refresh all your objects after logout.

Comment: the webbrowser not navigating on form close event

Comment: Some how you need to restrict the form closing event by checking the LOGOUT form is loaded in Webbrowser or not. After that you close the form.